# Undefined index: in ajax php datatable

Tags: php

tengo un pequeño problema al querer mostrar en una tabla los datos que pasan por una ruta GET osea de la vista lo manda a js y de js a ajax para mostrar en la tabla los datos, estos datos se ven sin problema sin ajax pero cuando aplico el ajax no me funciona y sale un error que no esta declarada la ruta GET pero ahora me quede en blanco porque probe cosas pero no me funcionan

JS

```html
(".datatablesentradas").DataTable({
   "ajax":"ajax/datatablesindividual/datatablesentradas.ajax.php",
  
    "responsive": true, 
    "lengthChange": true, 
    "aLengthMenu":[[10, 50, 100, 500, 1000],[10, 50, 100, 500, 1000]],
    "autoWidth": false,
    "processing":true,
    "serverSide": false,
    "order":[[0,"asc"]],
```

EN MI AJAX

```html
static public function mostrarTablaentrada(){
     
        
            $valor= $_GET["email_encriptado"];
            $categorias2 = ControladorPerfil::ctrMostrarId($valor);

        if(count($categorias2)== 0){

            $datosJson = '{"data": []}';

            echo $datosJson;

            return;

        }

        $datosJson = '{

        "data": [ ';



        foreach ($categorias2 as $key => $value) {
```

ERROR

**Notice**:  Undefined index: email_encriptado in **ajax/datatablesindividual/datatablesentradas.ajax.php** on line **20**
{"data": []}

Comment: Yo no veo ninguna propiedad llamada `email_encriptado` en los datos que estarías enviando al servidor. Pon un **`var_dump($_GET);`** en tu código y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: es que lo tengo en la vista

Comment: cuando ingresen a la vista    ControladorPerfil::ctrMostrarId($valor);  // $valor= $_GET["email_encriptado"];

Comment: ¿Depuraste como te dije en el primer comentario? ¿Qué ves en pantalla? Es una situación básica de depuración, si algo falla, entonces muestra eso que falla para verificar lo que tienes ahí.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: email_encriptado in ajax/datatablesindividual/datatablesentradas.ajax.php on line 20
{"data": []}

Comment: A ver, pon esto al principio de tu función en PHP:  **`var_dump($_GET);`** y dinos que muestra.